# Special characters in Php variable

Tags: php

In my code I am assigning value to php variable as

```
$firstname="shipping->firstname";
```

In my orders array, i am using the following inside foreach to get shipping address firstname,

```
$ShippingFirstName=$rvalue->$firstname;
```

But I am getting error,

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$&quot;shipping_address-&amp;gt;first_name&quot;
```

When I echo the $firstname variable I am getting shipping_address->first_name. But during execution it is converted. Please help.

I have tried htmlspecialchars_decode,str_replace,json_encode(htmlspecialchars($firstname)) but the same error.

Thanks,
Rekha

Comment: Such approach will not work.

Comment: shipping->firstname is already saved in an array in my database. I need to map that value during looping of order array.is there any solution?

Comment: @Rekha would you be familiar to share your database structure so that we could suggest better approaches than your current?

Comment: In my database, I am storing array of objects [{"tagfrom":"firstname",$tagto":"shipping->firstname"},{.....}] like this....I need to take values from tagto and get results from orders array.

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($rvalue);` then we can understand the structure of the object you are trying to take the data from. It's unclear how it relates to the array of objects you've mentioned in your database.

Comment: Looks like [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) would solve your problem. But remember, if you use eval, you'll end up in hell. Eval is evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i dont think this is possible but there is some tricks. like this one:

```
$firstname_iterators = explode('->',$firstname);

$ShippingFirstName=$rvalue->{$firstname_iterators[0]}()->{$firstname_iterators[1]};
```

---

if your are going to do more than one pointer then use this type

```
$ShippingFirstName=$rvalue;
foreach ($firstname_iterators as $key => $firstname_iterator) {
    $ShippingFirstName=$ShippingFirstName->{$firstname_iterator};
}
```

if this answer is ok mark it as correct answer so it can be usefull for someone else.

Comment: Yeah this is working fine. But is there any way to do this dynamically suppose if we have more than two iterators